# Why is the AWS SQS Purge Queue method not available?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk

I am working with AWS SQS in the AWS SDK for .NET.  The PurgeQueue method is not available, and I am not able to see this method in the list.

Is PurgeQueue version dependent?

Answer (score 1):

Purge Queue is available as of AWS SDK for .NET 2.3.12, released on December 9, 2014.

If you're still using V1 or an earlier version of V2, you will need to update to be able to use Purge Queue. Purge Queue is a relatively recent addition to SQS, so you're correct that it is version dependent as it is likewise a new addition to the various SDKs.

There are several Purge Queue options available on the [AmazonSQSClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TSQS_SQSNET4_5.html):

```
PurgeQueue(string)
PurgeQueue(PurgeQueueRequest)
PurgeQueueAsync(PurgeQueueRequest, CancellationToken)
```

Further reading:

- [AWS SDK for .NET 2.3.12 Release Notes](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/.NET/0010283313371741)